# Can we make sub menus using drawer navigation in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can we create sub-menus in drawer navigation as shown below image?

[Sub Menu in drawer navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HZ4D.png)

Comment: refer this link https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-nested-drawer-menu-with-react-native-a1c2fdcab6c9/

Comment: Do u have any snippet of it?

Comment: https://github.com/appbaseio-apps/native-kitchensink/tree/master/src/drawers